Find $t$ such that $\int_0^t x^x dx = 1$
So far, I know that $1<t$ and that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_1^t x^n (\ln{x})^n dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$$
I got this by using power series but I don't know where to go from here. Using a calculator I found that $t \approx 1.19491.$
Is there a closed form for $t$?

PARI GP: solve(t=1,2,1-intnum(x=0,t,if(x==0,1,x^x))) returns $1.1949070080264606819835589994757229370...$

$$\frac{5671639644304 \binom{e}{e!}+433077654421
\binom{e!}{e}}{2064749523021}$$ is in absolute error of  $5.10\times 10^{-39}$

Your first integral is for $\int_0^1$ instead of $\int_t^1$

No, Tyma Gaidash

@uggupuggu Rephrasing, your sum on the RHS is for now the Sophomore dream, but that requires  $-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 x^n (\ln{x})^n dx = \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$

$$\int_0^t x^x dx = 1$$
As far as I know there is no closed form for $t$.
A non-standardized closed form could be defined from the inverse of the Sphd$(1,t)$ function. But this would be purely symbolic without practical interest.
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function
As already pointed out by Jorge Zuniga numerical calculus provides very accurate
approximate.
$$t\simeq 1.194907008026...$$
One can find an infinity of empirical equations giving very close values of $t$. For exemple :
$$t\simeq \left(\frac{1}{2\,\gamma^3\,(\gamma+e^{-1})^2}\right)^{1/6}\simeq 1.194907008020...$$
$\gamma\simeq 0.577215664901533$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
The coincidence holds up to twelve digits. But this is pure coincidence as one can found a lot of coincidences thanks to some methods of experimental mathematics :
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales
In addition EXAMPLES OF OTHER COINCIDENCES
First example ( coincidence holding up to ten digits) :
$$\int_0^t x^x dx = e\quad\text{from numerical calculus : }\quad t\simeq 1.9703725259...$$
$$t\simeq \left(e^e+\frac{1}{\gamma} \right)^{1/3}\left(e^{-1}+e^K\right)\simeq 1.9703725262...$$
$\gamma\simeq 0.577215664901533...$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
$K\simeq 0.915965594177219...= $ is the Catalan constant.
Second example ( coincidence holding up to ten digits) :
$$\int_0^t x^x dx = \pi\quad\text{from numerical calculus : }\quad t\simeq 2.0722851702...$$
$$t\simeq \frac{e^{(K^{\,3})}}{\gamma\;(e+\pi)}\simeq 2.0722851709...$$
Those empirical formulas where obtained in a few minutes on an ordinary PC with the kind of I.S.C. software described in the paper quoted above.
Of course such councidences are for amusement only. They are meaningless.

Thanks for that document, how exactly did you find that approximation?

As said in my comment the numerical approximation was first given by Jorge Zuniga. I only chek it.

For the fun of not solving an equation
Using
$$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\,(x-1)^n$$ the first $a_n$ and $b_n$ corresponding to sequences $A082525$ and $A082526$ in $OEIS$
$$I=\int_0^t x^x\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\,\frac{(t-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{n+1}$$ Rewrite $I$ as
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\,(t-1)^n$$ Truncate to some order $p$ and use power series reversion to get rational numbers. Converted to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & t_{(p)} \\
 10 & 1.1992382 \\
 20 & 1.1960254 \\
 30 & 1.1953982 \\
 40 & 1.1951801 \\
 50 & 1.1950802 \\
 60 & 1.1950264 \\
 70 & 1.1949942 \\
 80 & 1.1949735 \\
 90 & 1.1949593 \\
 100 & 1.1949492 \\
 200 & 1.1949174 \\
 300 & 1.1949116 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ which, very slowly converges to the value given by @Jorge Zuniga in comments.
Now, searching the $ISC$ for simple numbers
$$t\sim \frac 6 5-\frac{1}{500}\, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\,\,
   \left(2\sqrt[3]{18}-\sqrt{10}\right)$$ which is in an absolute error of $3.39 \times 10^{-10}$ but which does not mean anything.
For this value, the result of numerical integration is $1.000000000419\cdots$.

Hi Claude ! Always ready to play with numbers... Cheers.

@JJacquelin. What amazed me was to solve the problem without solving the equation. Have a look at my comment just after Jorge Zuniga's comment. By the way, you made a very nice ISC. Cheers
